# What do all of these things have in common?

Tags: knowledge, visual

What do these five things have in common?

[image]

Hint:

> These images are in a specific order

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All of these pictures depict:

> Words which are spelled exclusively using letters which are also **Roman numerals**.

Like so:

> 1. **I** (pointing to oneself)
>  2. **XI** Jinping (General Secretary of the Communist Party of China)
>  3. **LI** (lithium batteries - 'Li' is the chemical symbol for Lithium in the Periodic Table)
>  4. **MI** (the third note in the Do-Re-Mi scale, equivalent to an 'E')
>  5. **MIX** (using a whisk)

The images are ordered:

> In ascending numerical order when converted to Roman numerals:
>  I (1), XI (11), LI (51), MI (1001), MIX (1009).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they all

> Rhyme, namely **me**, **Xi** (President Xi Jinping), **battery**, **E** (the musical note), and **she** (the girl with the whisk).

Comment: Great answer, but that's not it. I have added a hint.

Comment: I have replaced the last image to be a little more clear.